# Passing an argument to an expression and get output from it?

Tags: bash, shell

I currently have the following script:

```
var_name=`cat X | grep Y`
```

where X and Y are a filename and some string. I want to make this general and turn X and Y into the first and the second argument passing for the script. I tried

```
var_name=`cat $1 | grep $2`
```

and

```
var_name=`cat "$1" | grep "$2"`
```

but neither works.

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [FAQ] soon.  Both variants of what you tried should work for the simple cases where there are no spaces or shell metacharacters in the arguments `$1` and `$2`; the second (with double quotes) is better than the first for general use.  You should use `$(...)` instead of the back-ticks too, but that shouldn't affect what you see here.  What did you try?  How do you know it did not work?  What did you see when you ran `bash -x your_script /etc/passwd root`?

Comment: Also note that there's a UUOC award awaiting you.  `var_name=$(grep "$2" "$1")` should do the trick.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler UUOC?

Comment: Thanks. The simple test actually work. I must be doing something wrong else where. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: @hd1: I didn't realize Google wasn't working :D  [UUOC](http://catb.org/jargon/html/U/UUOC.html) — Useless Use Of Cat.

Comment: Or, a better URL for [UUOC](http://catb.org/jargon/html/U/UUOC.html).  The formatting on the one I quoted first is ... disappointing.

Comment: The second link, too, has formatting issues, and a stale link to the page now at http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments you may do a debug using bash -x to see what is going on. Also as mentioned the cat is not needed but still produces the result. Here is a short test. Maybe you revise your post and show your actual full program.

```
$>cat uuoc.sh
#!/bin/sh 
var_name=`cat "$1" | grep "$2"`
echo Result 1:
echo $var_name
var_name=`grep "$2" "$1"`
echo Result 2:
echo $var_name

$>cat myfile.txt
file 
with
pattern (1)
just
for
pattern (2)

$>./uuoc.sh myfile.txt pattern
Result 1:
pattern (1) pattern (2)
Result 2:
pattern (1) pattern (2)
```

Comment: You should still use double quotes around the variable interpolations, otherwise `./uuoc.sh file "two words"` will fail.